# Is there a way I can upload a new image of some resolution and feed it to model to get the image of doubled resolution?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I made the model using conv2dtranspose that can increase the resolution of image from 14×14 to 28x28. Is there a way I can upload a new image of some resolution and feed it to model to get the image of doubled resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just pass your `14x14` image into the network and see results, but I don't think transpose convolution will do a good job here.

Super resolution models are approximation of what the image would look like in higher resolution, you could check those ideas out.

Usually, those aren't trained for such small resolution though, but you may try some pretrained models to check the results and whether they are satisfactory.